# CodeIgniter : for each loop Attempt to assign property 'details' of non-object

Tags: php, loops, codeigniter

i am fetching data from two tables as below :

```
$form['form']=json_decode($this->db->get_where('forms',array(
    'id'    => $id
))->result()[0]->form_sections);
```

This gives me following result on printing :

```
Array
(
    [form] => Array
        (
            [0] => Personal_Information
            [1] => Education_
            [2] => Professional_Life
        )

)
```

Now i have details against each of these array indexes that i am trying to assign them as below

```
   foreach ($form['form'] as  $value){
    $value->details=$this->db->get_where('formdata',array(
        'form_section'  => $value
            ))->result();
    }
```

Which gives me following error

> Message: Attempt to assign property 'details' of non-object

can someone please help me to sort out the issue , i have to assign the index and loop in it in my view

Answer (score 0):

This should help understand and clear up the message:

```
// Custom data
$Person_Info = 404; // Could be any non-object
$array = array("form" => array( 0 => $Person_Info) );
              
foreach( $array['form'] as $value ){
    $results = new stdClass();
    $results->name = "User A";
    
    $value->details = $results; // $results are you fetch request
}
// Output: Attempt to assign property 'details' of non-object in php<8.0
// Output: Uncaught Error: Attempt to assign property "details" on int php>=8.0
```

Try to `print_r` or `var_dump` your `$value` and see what you are getting. It's not an object for some of your array item.

Edit: If ever in doubt about the data. Use `if (is_obejct($var))` [php.net/is_object](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-object.php) or similar checks based on what you need.